# find child element of div with jquery and update the html

Tags: jquery, html, find, element, children

I am having an hard time trying to update a blog post with new comments on the fly using jquery. my html is set as:

```
<div class="card-block" id="comments_{{$i->id}}">
    <p class="card-text"><a href="#">{{$i->user->username}}</a> {{$i->description}}</p>
    <hr>
    <div class="card_block">
        <form id="post_{{$i->id}}" class="dynamic-form" style="display:none" method="post" action="/comment/add">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="{{ $i->id }}">
            <div class="form-group" id="DynCommentInput">
                <textarea required="required" placeholder="Enter comment here" name="body" class="form-control"></textarea>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" name='post_comment' class="btn btn-success" value="Post"/>
        </form>
    </div>
    <p class="card-text new_comment_{{$i->id}}" style="display:none"></p>
    @if($i->comments)
        @foreach($i->comments as $c)
            <p class="card-text"><a href="#">{{$c->author->username}}</a> {{$c->body}}</p>
        @endforeach
    @endif
</div>
```

and this the jquery:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("body").on("submit", ".dynamic-form", function (e) {

            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var new_comment_id = '.new_comment_' + id;
            var comments_id = '#comments_' + id;
            var form = $(this);

            $.ajax({
                url: form.prop('action'),
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data) {

                    var resultStr = "";

                    resultStr = resultStr + "<a href=\"#\"><\/a>" + data.body ;

                    console.log(resultStr);

                    $(comments_id).find(new_comment_id).html(resultStr).slideToggle(150).promise().done(function () {
                        $(new_comment_id).fadeIn("fast");
                    });
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
});
```

The latter should insert resultStr in the `<p>` element in the page with `class="card-text new_comment_{{$i->id}}"` but nothing happens once I click submit for the new post. a `console.log(data);` shows the post being passed so it's not a controller problem but that jquery code.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `.` at the beginning of `new_comment_id` so that it will match the class (and wouldn't it be clearer to call this `new_comment_class`?).

```
var new_comment_id = '.new_comment_' + id;
```

Another problem is that the ID of the form is `post_##`, so you're setting `comment_id` and `new_comment_id` to `#comments_post_##` and `.new_comment_post_##`, respectively. You need to remove the `post_` prefix when setting `id`:

```
var id = this.id.replace('post_', '');
```

Although all this use of the ID seems unnecessary. You could simply do:

```
var new_comments = $(this).closest(".card-block").find(".card-text");
```

and then in the callback function:

```
new_comments.html(resultStr).slideToggle(150)promise().done(function ...);
```

Comment: made some edits, check the original question. Still doesn't work.

Comment: thanks, I didn't realize I was messing with the id. As for the id what if then I want to delete comments? I need to identify those by ids in the db.

Comment: I usually put the database row ID in a `data-XXX` attribute.